# Is possible to get a SPListItemCollection by just a URL of its SPList?

Tags: server

In my project, I have to get the SpListItemCollection of the splist by the url that user entered. However, I cannot get anything by just using it.

To get a SPListItemCollection:

```
1) get SPSite object (site collection)
2) get SPWeb object (sub site (optional))
3) get SPList object (Guid, list name...)
```

The URL I received:

http://aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Do you guy have any idea to  split the URL to fill the items?

Comment: Yes, what language are we working with here? As it stands, there are too many potential ways.

Comment: @EricAlexander HI, does this answer fit my post? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77510/is-it-possible-to-get-an-splist-object-with-just-a-url

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN,

The URL that is passed to the SPSite constructor does not need to match a site collection URL exactly. See examples below.

The following code example returns the site collection that is located at http://Server_Name/sites/Site_Name even though the URL that is passed to the constructor does not match the site collection URL.

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://Server_Name/sites/Site_Name/Subsite_Name/default.aspx"))
{
    ...
}
```

So you can use as below and get site collection object....

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
```

From here you can get list items based on view/caml query etc....